# How to send data though AJAX to another controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

This is my Laravel Route

```
Route::resources('classes','ClassController');
//For AJAX
Route::post('/classes/students','ClassController@classStudents');
```

This is my Html form. When Submit Bottom is clicked i just need to send data from AJAX for two input type student_name & roll_no. For Student_name and roll_no input type I have used Dynamic Input table JQuery where 1 class contain many student name and roll no. So I need to send data of student and roll no though AJAX

```
<form action="{{route('classes.store')}}" method="POST" >
    <input type="text" name="class_name" placeholder="Enter Class Name">
    <input type="number" name="class_teacher" placeholder="Enter Class Teacher name">
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
             <input type="text" name="student_name[]" id="student_name" placeholder="Enter student 
              name">
          </td>
          <td>
              <input type="text" name="roll_no[]" id="roll_number" placeholder="Enter Roll no">
          </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   <button type="submit" id="classForm">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is my script file. So how to send two input data though AJAX ?

```
    
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('#classForm').click(function(e) {
                var student_name=('input[id=student_name]');
                 var roll_no=('input[id=roll_no]');
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/classes/students',
                    type: "POST",
                  success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data)
                    }
                })
            });

            return false;
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: I dont understand why you want to send them on different endpoint then the one you set on form action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *only* want to send through AJAX, just remove the form elements and use a trigger on the button like my first example below.   Assuming you want both for some reason - perhaps add a different button for AJAX only sends, something like:

```
<button type="button" id="classFormAjax">Submit Instant</button>
```

Then, you can send the data via ajax:

```
   $('#classFormAjax').click(function(e) {
       $.ajax({
           url: '/classes/students',
           type: "POST",
           // Make sure you add an id to your form for this to work
           data : $('#form').serialize() 
           success: function(data) {
               console.log(data)
           }
       })
   });
```

If you use your original button, which is a type `submit`, you just have to block the form from sending... though not sure the use case of this:

```
        $('#classFormAjax').click(function(e) {
           // Prevent the form from submitting:
           e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/classes/students',
                type: "POST",
                // Make sure you add an id to your form for this to work
                data : $('#form').serialize() 
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data)
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: No I need to send class name and class teacher in another controller route=classes.store and student name and rolle number into another contoller

Comment: Do it exactly as in the answer above.  From the **controller** method, send the information to the second controller.  No sense in having two form requests, instead send the information from the controller to the second controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i didnot understand why data:$('#form').serialize(). Doesnot i need to use student_name and rolle no id ?
Donot get mad at me i asked silly question.

Comment: No silly at all :)  Yes, you can get those params from the request in the first controller.  Then, you can send whatever param you want from that first controller to the second.  Just trying to avoid two posts from the form - grab all the data in your controller from the first form send (this will include BOTH `student_name` and `roll_no_id`), then from your controller send whatever variable you wish into the second controller :)

Comment: Okay Last Question 
How can i  stringified the array  coming from student_name and roll_no and send it to the controller ? Can you show me ?

Comment: If I have 2000 student_name and 2000 roll no Ofcouse Error will come "i think like nput-variables-exceeded-1000".So i need to stringified the array and send it to controller so I can decode it .I hope you will help this one. Thanks a million although

Comment: From the controller to the page?  Use the php function `compact` when returning the view.  Example: `return view('something.myPage', compact('student_names','roll_no'));`  From the form *page to the controller*, everything already comes in as a string.